# Bootstrap collapse are making an overlay on next Bootstrap collapse header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am making a website as my wishlist this year. Every wish has a collapsible menu (made with Bootstrap collapse) and something is not right.

Problem illustrated in picture:
[image]

As you can see, it is like the collapsible element is overlaying or a part of the next panel that should trigger the next collapsible element.

I have looked for bugs in my code multiple times and I really can't figure out why it is doing this.

So the

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
```

is overlaying the

```
<a class="panel-link" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
```

All of my code is in a Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/RasmusLauridsen/pen/EgByYx).

*My website is in Danish :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First of all, you need to fix the hierarchy of HTML-tags. Which tag should be within another?

```
<a class="panel-link" ...>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
    ...        
    </a>
    ...
    <a class="#" ...>
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

2) Bootstrap's [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) involves one more hierarchy of blocks: the container contains rows and rows contain columns. So you need to wrap columns into rows.

See [demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/ZpdONW).

Comment: I can't see any problems in the hierarchy in this code?
All the tags are closed and in the right order?

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen Two `<div>` blocks are opened inside the first link and closed inside the second one.

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen I've updated my answer. Please check the solution.

Comment: Oh. You are right! I forgot that rows .. Thank you!